# Reduce input sensitivity in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made an Isometric character controller so it can move and head on an isometric based perspective. The problem is that when I try to move using 2 keys (W + D, A + S...) and release those keys, the player tends to face the very last key that was released, so it is difficult to head a diagonal direction. This makes the character flip its rotation in the very last moment the keys are released.

I've been thinking of using a kind of sleep or coroutine checking if two keys were pressed and released in a short period of time just not rotate it.

There exist any not too rustic solution for this?

Here is my code (I just copied it from here: https://www.studica.com/blog/isometric-camera-unity)

```
    private void SetIsometricDirections() {
        vertical = Camera.main.transform.forward;
        vertical.y = 0;
        vertical = Vector3.Normalize(vertical);
        horizontal = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 90, 0)) * vertical;
    }

    private void Move() {
        Vector3 horizontalMovement = horizontal * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("HorizontalKey");
        Vector3 verticalMovement = vertical * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("VerticalKey");
        Vector3 heading = Vector3.Normalize(horizontalMovement + verticalMovement);
        Heading(heading);
        transform.position += (horizontalMovement + verticalMovement);
    }

    private void Heading(Vector3 heading) {
        transform.forward = heading;
    }
```

The heading trick it's in the "Heading" method, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. 
I'll post it just in case any one else needs it in the future.

I calculate the current rotation based on the movement.

```
private void SetRotation() {
    currentRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movement);
}
```

Then, I created a second Quaternion to store the last rotation if is not the same than the current. I also use a counter to store the time a rotation has been faced before stopping the movement or changing the direction.

```
private void CheckSameRotation() {
    if (lastRotation != currentRotation || movement == Vector3.zero) {
            sameRotationTime = 0;
            lastRotation = currentRotation;
    }
    else {
        sameRotationTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Then, I used a bool to check if the time is high enough to make the rotation happen.

```
private void TimeAtSameRotation() {
    canRotate = (sameRotationTime < 0.015f) ? false : true;
}
```

And then, I finally rotate the object if the movement is not zero and the condition "canRotate" is true.

```
private void Rotate() {
    if (movement != Vector3.zero && canRotate) {
        transform.rotation = currentRotation;
    }
}
```